# How to tell when execution is complete in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

`func1()` calls `func2()` twice. `func2()` calls `func3()` a variable number of times (based on a parameter that is passed to it). As `node.js` is asynchronous, how can I tell when the last call to `func3()` has finished executing? Assume I do not know how many times `func3()` would be called.

This ought to be simple but is definitely out of my reach.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `async`-Package to handle asynchronous calls: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: `async` package can help you, but if you don't want to use any dependencies please post some of your code so its easier to help!

Answer (score 0):

Without async you may simply writes console.log('yep') or many others at end of code-block of func3(). If you want - write there you code for details of help.